# CSS transition not working on Safari for pseudo elements

Tags: css

I know there is plenty of documentation on this and according to this post by Chris Coyier https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/ Safari 6.1 and up support transitions on pseudo elements. I have tested my code on Chrome and Firefox and my transition works however on Safari 6.2.3 there is no transition. The pseudo element moves right but it is jarring and happens immediately. i.e. the transition property is not being applied.

This is my code. The fontello include just includes an icon.

```
@mixin animation-right($font-size: $base-font-size) {
  &:after {
    @include transition(transform 300ms ease); 
    $font-size: $font-size;
    color: $color-blue-bright;
    @include fontello(
      $icon: $icon-arrow-right,
      $height: .8em
    );
    font-size: em($font-size, $base-font-size);
    margin-left: em(10px);
  }

  &:hover,
  &:focus, {
    &:after {
      @include translateX(100%);
      @include fontello(
        $icon: $icon-right,
        $height: 1em
      );
      color: $color-orange;
    }
  }  
}
```

It's applied like this:

```
a {
  @include animation-right($font-size: 14px);
}
```

As I said, it's working on Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of the transition mixin and what kind of parameters you can assign to it? If the parameter is '$value...' you maybe need to add the -webkit prefix:

`@include transition(transform 300ms ease, -webkit-transform 300ms ease);`

p.s. Long time ago I had some issues when I was trying to transition translate property with percentage value (the animation was a lot more smoother).

Comment: It's the compass transition mixin. http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/ It should take care of prefixing.

Comment: I suggest you to check the generated css and look for the transform property. You also make sure to remove the comma after &:focus